# XSL: how to improve this code?

Tags: xml, xslt

Sorry, I'm learning XSL and I would like to display a table like this:

```
|   Param1    | Param2 |
-------+------+---------
| p1.1 | p1.2 |   p2   |
-------+------+---------
|  a11 |  a21 |   b01  |
|  a12 |  a22 |   b02  |
```

now, I have a xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <tb>
    <col title="Param1">
        <row name="1">
        <stats name="p1.1" >a11</stats>
        <stats name="p1.2" >a12</stats>
        </row>
        <row name="2">
        <stats name="p1.1" >a21</stats>
        <stats name="p1.2" >a22</stats>
        </row>
    </col>
    <col title="Param2">
        <row name="1">
        <stats name="p2" >b01</stats>
        </row>
        <row name="2">
        <stats name="p2" >b02</stats>
        </row>
    </col>
```

and xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:for-each select="tb">
    <table class="data_table" style="width: 100%; background:gray">
        <thead>
          <tr>
         <xsl:for-each select="col">
            <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="count(row[1]/stats) > 1">
                <th colspan="{count(row[1]/stats)}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="@title" />
                </th>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <th><xsl:value-of select="@title" /></th>
            </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <xsl:for-each select="col/row[1]/stats">
            <th><xsl:value-of select="@name" /></th>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

           <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="col/row[1]/stats">
                <td>
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </td>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="col/row[2]/stats">
                <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="." />
            </td>
                    </xsl:for-each>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
   </xsl:for-each>
```

It's works but how do I improve this code using a single FOR to assemble the table rows? In the example I have only 2 rows (a11|a21|b01 and a12|a22|b02) and 3 columns but this may change (20 rows, 4 columns...). Maybe I need to group the cells belonging to the same row.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first thing to do to improve your XSLT is to use templates. Once that's done, you can do the following to be able to handle an arbitrary number of rows.

This solution assumes that every `<col>` in your source data will have a `<row>` for every row that you need:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/tb">
    <table class="data_table" style="width: 100%; background:gray">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="col" mode="titles" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="col/row[1]/stats" mode="titles" />
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="col[1]/row" />
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col" mode="titles">
    <th>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="(.)[row[1]/stats[2]]" mode="colSpan" />
      <xsl:value-of select="@title"/>
    </th>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="col" mode="colSpan">
    <xsl:attribute name="colspan">
      <xsl:value-of select="count(row[1]/stats)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="stats" mode="titles">
    <th>
      <xsl:value-of select="@name" />
    </th>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="row">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../../col/row[@name = current()/@name]/stats" /> 
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="stats">
    <td>
      <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </td>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<table class="data_table" style="width: 100%; background:gray">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Param1</th>
      <th>Param2</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>p1.1</th>
      <th>p1.2</th>
      <th>p2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>a11</td>
      <td>a12</td>
      <td>b01</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>a21</td>
      <td>a22</td>
      <td>b02</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```